# Color points on CGAL Triangulation_3

Tags: colors, point, cgal, triangulation

I am trying to give a color to the points into a triangulation_3 on CGAL. I just take the example from CGAL describe [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_3/Triangulation_3_2color_8cpp-example.html)

I made a simple modification on this example to be able to draw the triangulation:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_cell_base_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3.h>
#include <CGAL/IO/Color.h>
#include <CGAL/draw_triangulation_3.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel         K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_3<CGAL::Color, K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_cell_base_3<K>                 Cb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_3<Vb, Cb>                Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K, Tds>                      Delaunay;
typedef Delaunay::Point                                             Point;
int main()
{
  Delaunay T;
  T.insert(Point(0,0,0));
  T.insert(Point(1,0,0));
  T.insert(Point(0,1,0));
  T.insert(Point(0,0,1));
  T.insert(Point(2,2,2));
  T.insert(Point(-1,0,1));
  // Set the color of finite vertices of degree 6 to red.
  Delaunay::Finite_vertices_iterator vit;
  for (Delaunay::Vertex_handle v : T.finite_vertex_handles())
      if (T.degree(v) == 6)
    v->info() = CGAL::Color(0,255,0);

  CGAL::draw(T);
  return 0;
}
```

But no matter which color I put on `v->info() = CGAL::Color(0,255,0);` the method draw always give the same red points in the window displayed:

[image: Triangulation]

I understand that the code is constructing a data structure that contains color information but this could be independent of the draw method, so i think that the window doesn't show me green points because this is not the way to color the points. If so, what is the way to get a triangulation with green points using the draw method?'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its current form, the viewer is not able to change the color of vertices nor edges.

But it is easy to change the code.

1. Copy the file [draw_triangulation_3.h](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/releases/CGAL-5.0.2/Triangulation_3/include/CGAL/draw_triangulation_3.h) in your project
2. edit the method [`void compute_vertex(Vertex_const_handle vh)`](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/7a1ba12bab47123e5adc4536afef0359fb53ed97/Triangulation_3/include/CGAL/draw_triangulation_3.h#L92), (line 92 in this file) to use the add_point method with a color as parameter: `add_point(vh->point(), vh->info());`